# How to execute a stepped increase of values in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to increase every 3rd number by a value of 5 to result in

```
A = [1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 11, 7, 8, 14, 10]
```

My gut tells me something along the lines of

```
A[::3] = [x + 5 for x in A]
```

OR using the loop below with replace somehow integrated

```
for num in range(0, len(A), 3):
    A = num + 5
```

Send help...thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try any of these approaches?

Comment: `A[2::3] = [x+5 for x in A[2::3]]`

Comment: @PaulH yes, else I wouldn't have asked this question. I suspected I was close but overlooking something small.

Comment: @Blorgbeard this solution is both simple and works exactly as I was hoping. Seems I had missed inserting the slicing into the equation as well. Would you like to put your answer in a response so I can give you the vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it with your first attempt.

Modify the slice to start at the 3rd element (index 2) per your example, and make sure to read the same slice that you're writing to:

```
A[2::3] = [x+5 for x in A[2::3]]
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do it

```
A=[x+5 if i%3==0 else x for i,x in enumerate(A,1)]
```

Comment: You're making some assumptions about the content of the list there. If there are any repeats, it doesn't necessarily work. And give me a minute to comment :P

Comment: @Blorgbeard i'm not making any assumptions. He says he has **this** input and wants **that** output

Comment: Then you could just hardcode the output. It's a reasonable assumption that OP wants code that works for *other* input as well.

Comment: What? That works for every "reasonable" list? What assumptions are you talking about

Comment: Changed mine to an upvote, edited code is fine. Although it can be done in less code by assigning to a slice, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function for it which would account for duplicate values or unsorted values.  If my assumptions are not correct, you could easily adjust the function to get your values correct.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 8, 9, 7]

def list_modifier(passed_list):

    passed_list.sort()

    mod_list = list(set(passed_list))

    out_list = {i:i if (mod_list.index(i)+1)%3 != 0 else (i+5) for i in mod_list }

    passed_list = [out_list[i] for i in out_list]

    return passed_list

list_modifier(A)
```

Returned list looks like this:
[1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 11, 7, 8, 14, 10]

Comment: I don't think that OP wants the list sorted and deduplicated. I think the fact that their example was `list(range(1,11))` is just because it's easy to see the desired modifications.

Comment: Absolutely, it's all variable.  I did it this way because of other points made.  Otherwise the other answer is what I would have submitted.